# Private templates in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

In Google Drive you can right-click on a document and hit "submit to template gallery" when you go through to there you can submit your template, but that makes it public on the web so any one can access it.

Is there a way you can build your own template gallery, for just your account or with permissions so you could allow other people access it, just in the same way you share a doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lady has a nifty solution to your query: http://www.alicekeeler.com/teachertech/2014/12/10/google-docs-force-students-to-make-a-copy/

Ensure also that the document is visible to anyone who has the link. You may do this by clicking on the **Get link** icon (the icon which looks like a paper clip on the upper right-hand of the panel when you click once a doc in Google Drive), then the **Sharing settings** link, then the **Get shareable link** icon. Afterwards, change the document's accessibility to "Anyone with the link can view/edit/comment" (whichever suits your preference, though I prefer the view or comment option so that the collaborators cannot edit the original template directly).

The same lady also suggested in a similar outdated blog that, for convenience in sharing the link, it would be better to use a URL shortener (such as https://goo.gl) for the whole link to the document clone (i.e., including the appended /copy at the end of the URL)

I tried her suggestion and it works!

Answer (score 3):

The best way I've found is to create a Google Doc file as a Template and give it a name like **Template for foo** Then when you are ready to invoke the template, click on it in Google Docs and then select More -> Make a Copy. Then you can change the copy's name and add content. It isn't the smoothest way, but it at least allows you to reuse and is fairly accessible.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you want to make global changes you can't.

Comment: @manumoomoo this is true, but don't believe that option exists in Google Doc

Comment: it does for business accounts.

Comment: Cool. Do you happen to have a reference link? I'm curious how they structure it.